# A problem of the limit of $\frac{\sup_{0<\lvert y\rvert\leq \delta}\lvert f(x+y)-f(x)\rvert}{\delta^{a}}$

Tags: limits-and-convergence

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$. For $0<a<1$, if
$$ \varlimsup_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sup_{0<\lvert y\rvert\leq \delta}\lvert f(x+y)-f(x)\rvert}{\delta^{a}} = \infty, $$
then, given any $\epsilon>0$, is it true that
$$ \varliminf_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sup_{0<\lvert y\rvert\leq \delta}\lvert f(x+y)-f(x)\rvert}{\delta^{a+\epsilon}} = \infty? $$

Comment: What about $f(r)=r^{a-\epsilon}$ for some small $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @Echo Its lower limit is infinite.

Comment: Ok, lets rename it, say $f(r)=r^{a-\delta}$ for some small $\delta>0$? As soon as $\epsilon>\delta$, you're in trouble. Finally, you let $\delta$ shrink with $r$.

Comment: @Echo Do you mean $f(r) = r^{a-r}$?

Comment: @Echo The dominator in the lower limit is $\delta^{a+\epsilon}$.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be some fixed number of $[0,1]$ or in both cases you mean that the conditions hold for all $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is not continuous, but one can replace the jumps with linear pieces of fast growing slopes. Fix $0<\epsilon<a$. Define a sequence $(r_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ tending to zero inductively as follows:
$r_1=1$ and $0<r_{j+1}<r_j$ so small that
$$
\frac{r_{j+1}^{a-\epsilon}}{r_j^{a+\epsilon}}\le 1.
$$
Then set
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}0&t=0,\\ r_{j+1}^{a-\epsilon}& r_{j+1}<t\le r_j,\\
1&t>1.
\end{cases}
$$
We have
$$
\limsup\frac{f(t)}{t^a}=\lim_j\frac{f^+(r_{j+1})}{r_{j+1}^a}=\lim_j\frac{r_{j+1}^{a-\epsilon}}{r_{j+1}^a}=\infty
$$
while on the other hand
$$
\liminf \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+\epsilon}}=\lim_j\frac{f(r_j)}{r_j^{a+\epsilon}}=\frac{r_{j+1}^{a-\epsilon}}{r_{j}^{a+\epsilon}}\le 1.
$$

Comment: Your sequence $r_j$ is kind of weird. Its ratio $r_{j+1}/r_j$ converges faster than $r_j$. Could you please example one sequence like this?

Comment: Say $r_{j+1}=r_j^{\frac{a-\epsilon}{a+\epsilon}}$.